# cumsum data in between rows using pandas instead of loop

Tags: python, pandas

below are two columns, I want to cumsum data between zeros use another column's data. Note zero is just a marker that can be replaced by any variable. It is just used to indicate.
I want to cumsum use column time diff's data and assign it to time adder

```
time_diff                 
0                         
0 days 00:45             
0 days 00:30              
0 days 02:30              
...                       
0        

time_adder
0
NaN
NaN
NaN
...
0
```

I want to make the top like below:

```
time_adder
0
0 days 00:45          
0 days 01:15
0 days 03:45 
...
0
```

I made it use while loop:

```
i=0
adder=timedelta(hours=0)
while i<len(df['time_diff']):
    if df.loc[i,'time_adder']!=0:
        df.loc[i,'time_adder']=df.loc[i,'time_diff']+adder
        adder=df.loc[i,'time_adder']
    else:
        adder = timedelta(hours=0)
    i+=1
```

to clarify the time_adder column looks like:

```
[0 0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 0 0 NaN NaN 0 0 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN 0 0 ...].T
```

one more clarification:
cumsum the value in between zeros, and start cumsum refresh.
suppose we have time_adder:

```
[0 0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 0 0 NaN NaN 0 0 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN 0 0 ...].T
```

suppose we have time_diff:

```
[1 2  1   2   3   4  1 3  5   6  . . . . .   6  7  8 .........].T
```

the result of time adder should look like:

```
[0 0  1   3   6   10  0 0  5  11 0 0 0 0 0  6 13 21 0 0...].T
```

I wander if there is another way not use while loop I mean maybe use pandas groupby or apply lambda. Use while loop whould cost time and memory.

Comment: running a while loop seems cost a lot memory and made run time slow

Comment: Did you try with https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html?

Comment: there are bunch of zeros in different places, I want to cumsum data between them.

Comment: the data looks like :
[0 0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 0 0 NaN NaN 0 0 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN 0 0 ...]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc` to access only the records without the marker, and then apply `numpy.cumsum`.

```
import numpy as np    

df.loc[(df['time_adder'] != 0), 'time_adder'] = np.cumsum(df.loc[(df['time_diff'] != 0), 'time_diff'])
```

Note that you do need to use `loc` twice here.

`df.loc[(df['time_diff'] != 0), 'time_diff']` is necessary to ensure the cumsum is performed only on the records without the marker.

`df.loc[(df['time_adder'] != 0), 'time_adder']` specifies which records in the time_adder column to replace.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your suggestion would cumsum everything except rows with 0. I want to cumsum refresh after 0 zeros